# A more efficient .RData?

Tags: r

I am working with large data sets and often switch between my work station and laptop. Saving a workspace image to .RData is for me the most natural and convenient way, so this is the file that I want to synchronize between the two computers.

Unfortunately, it tends to be rather big (a few GB), so efficient synchronisation either requires me to connect my laptop with a cable or moving the files with a USB stick. If I forgot to synchronize my laptop when I was next to my workstation, it takes me hours to make sure everything is synchronized.

The largest objects, however, change relatively rarely (although I constantly work with them). I could save them to another file, and then delete them before saving the session and load them after restoring the session. This would work, but would be extremely annoying. Also, I would have to remember to save them whenever they are modified. It would soon end up being a total mess.

Is there more efficient way of dealing with such large data chunks?

For example, my problem would be solved if there was an alternative format to .RData -- one in which .RData is a directory, and files in that directory are objects to be loaded.

Comment: The usual answer to this question is to use one of the several interfaces to an SQL database, or to use an R package designed for improved speed such as `data.table` or `ff`.

Comment: How does using data.table improve the performance of *syncing the stored data*?

Comment: `data.table` has a faster input function: `fread`.

Comment: Yes. And how does this improve the performance of *syncing the stored data*? :-)) You know, when R is not even running? When I am syncing between my workstation and my laptop? As mentioned in my question, saving to disk is not the bottleneck. Transferring over wireless is.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your workflow and your use of the term "syncing". (Simply repeating with added italics to words does not necessarily add meaning.)

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat I'm sorry for that. Here is a link that explains the meaning of the word *syncing* that I use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_synchronization (read the first sentence). `data.table` is a fine package, and I *do* use it, but it does not solve my problem. In any case, thank you for your help. I didn't know this thing about italics! I thought it **always** adds meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `saveRDS`:

```
objs.names <- ls()
objs <- mget(objs.names) 
invisible(
  lapply(
    seq_along(objs), 
    function(x) saveRDS(objs[[x]], paste0("mydatafolder/", objs.names[[x]], ".rds"))
) )
```

This will save every object in your session to the "mydatafolder" folder as a separate file (make sure to create the folder before hand).

Unfortunately, this will modify the timestamps of all objects, you can't rely on `rsync`.  You could first read the objects in with `readRDS`, see which ones have changed with `identical`, and only run the `lapply` above on the changed objects so you can then use something like `rsync`.

Comment: OK, this seems to go in the right direction; I will have to think how to do it more or less automagically. Timestamps might not be necessary with unison.

Comment: @January Unison is how I'd prob do it; maybe git or Dropbox are worth looking into.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley This is outside of the discussion, but after having tried intesively Dropbox, unison, simple rsync and not-so-simple git I decided for unison.